# Can a loop be performed to run through a set of defined variables?

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word

I’m working on some code and wondering if a loop is possible. I’m actually writing this code for Word and not Excel which I normally do but I don’t think that matters. My vba skill level is beginner-intermediate I’d say. The code is meant to use the mail merge feature in Word which changes a few features in the document, and then perform a save-as on the file, then move on to the next file.

```
Sub Finsh_Merge_Save_302()


Dim date1 As String
Dim date2 As String
Dim filepath As String
Dim mainfile As String



Dim fund1 As String, fund2 As String, fund3 As String, fund4 As String 'etc.

Dim fundabbv1 As String, fundabbv2 As String, fundabbv3 As String, fundabbv4 As String ' etc.

mainfile = ActiveDocument.Name

fund1 = "blah blah blah 1"
fund2 = "blah blah blah 2"
fund3 = "blah blah blah x"
fund4 = "blah blah blah y"
'etc.

fundabbv1 = " stuff here 1"
fundabbv2 = " stuff here 2"
fundabbv3 = " stuff here x"
fundabbv4 = " stuff here y"
'etc.




    date1 = InputBox("Enter year of filing: 20xx")
    date2 = InputBox("Enter full date of filing: mm-dd-yyyy")
    filepath = "\\Bp211\sys\FAD\FA\TRES (March 2015)\Financial Reporting\Certifications\SOX Compliance and Certifications\N-CSR Certifications\NCSR Filings\" & date1 & "\" & date2

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
            .LastRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=filepath & "\" & fund1 & "\NCSR 302 Certifications" & fundabbv1 & ".docx"
    ActiveDocument.Close

    Windows(mainfile).Activate
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord



    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
            .LastRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=filepath & "\" & fund2 & "\NCSR 302 Certifications" & fundabbv2 & ".docx"
    ActiveDocument.Close

    Windows(mainfile).Activate
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
```

You can see where I'm using defined variables to save the file to the correct file location with the correct file name. Currently this works without a problem. The issue is I have many defined variables, 70+, so I was wondering if I could create a loop instead of writing that section of code 70+ times.

Comment: Input your variables inside one array and loop through it, if you have so many I'd write them into cells in one worksheet and then `MyArray = Sheets("MySheet").Range("A1:A100").Value` for example, you will get a 2d array that you can loop and your filenames will be on `MyArray(i, 1)`

Comment: Where are these variables coming from? Is this static text of some kind? Or is it being pulled in from a data source? Do you really mean Word's mail merge functionality, or when you say "mail merge" you mean merging information into a Word document, generally? Right off-hand, I'd question hard-coding the information for 70 variables into the macro. If any of these locations changes it means changing the macro. Better to read the information from a more easily managed source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using Arrays. You can use `Dim fund(1 To 4) As String` to declare an array and `fund(1)` to get the value at position 1, `fund(2)` to get the value at position 2, etc.

You can iterate over them by either using an index counter

```
For i = LBound(fund) To UBound(fund)
   MsgBox fund(i)
Next i
```

or with a for each

```
For Each element In fund
   MsgBox element
Next element
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Nirostar - your answer was what I needed. This quickly loops through all the files!

```
For i = LBound(fund) To UBound(fund)

    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
            .LastRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=filepath & "\" & fund(i) & "\NCSR 302 Certifications" & fundabbv(i) & ".docx"
    ActiveDocument.Close

    Windows(mainfile).Activate
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord

Next i
```